# Is Naath Sampradaya on the verge of extinction?

Tags: vedanta

The great Naath Sampradaya is a jewel of Hinduism. Saint Gyaneshwar from Maharashtra belonged to the Naath Sampradaya. But there has been no significant personality after him who preached Vedanta. Has anyone come across any Naath Sadhu recently. Why we don't see them even in Kumbha Mela? 
Does this mean Naath Sampradaya is on the verge of extinction?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nisargadatta_Maharaj was a recent sage who followed the natha sampradaya. Not sure if they count, though.

Comment: No way. This is one of the most prevalent tantric sects today. They have about twelve subsects and very popular in north, west and central India. Thousands or may be lacs of people.

Comment: Ok, glad to know that!!

Comment: Naaths are not vedantins. They are more into yoga and tantra preached by goraksha natha. Sant Jnaneshwar was mainly into bhakti movement and his brother nivriti nath was mainly into naath panth he was disciple of gahini nath.

Comment: Even the hon. Chief minister of U.P yogi aditya nath is initiated into nath parampara.

Comment: You will see natha yogis and such in places like Ujjain. They may not roam the roads freely but easier to locate them in such pilgrim centers.

Comment: Naaths are pretty much there infact there "science" is being revived actively. Go to any KumbhMela and search for the most popular Sanyasis there and their links with Naaths